# Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH

Tags: android

My problem is that the TORCH MODE is disabled when the get function onPictureTaken.
How to make a  torch mode on work during a photographic survey?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question right.
Did you try setting the camera parameters?

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera .getParameters();
parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);

. 
.
.

// Take image
```

Comment: I put the camera settings, but the FLASH_MODE_TORCH off , before when i get picture .

Comment: Do you set it before setting the preview display?

Comment: public void onClick(View v)
      {
  
 

                if (v == shot)
                {
                Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
                      params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                      camera.setParameters(params);
                      camera.takePicture(null, null, null, this);      
                }